# How to make NGINX work on tls1_2 instead of tls1_3 for specific IP

Tags: nginx, tls1.2, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

There is NGINX server working on tls1_3 protocol. Need to deny tls1_3 and allow tls1_2 for specific IP. OpenSSL 1.1.1.

NGINX works as proxy for Jira/Confluence. How config should looks like to implement that?

```
    server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    include acme;
    location /synchrony {
            allow 127.0.0.0/8;
            allow xxx;
            deny all;
            ...
    }

    location / {
            allow 127.0.0.0/8;
            allow xxx;
            allow xxx;
            deny all;
            ...
    }
    ssl on;
    ...
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'xxx'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By all means not a complete config below, but to give you idea and how you achieve this - is by use of streams.

The `ssl_protocols` directive does not support variables. However, its value can be different across `server {}` blocks.

So you can partition your existing `server` into two special `server`s and have NGINX do the necessary routing to the appropriate `server` using streams:

```
upstream normal {
    server 127.0.0.1:4443;
}
upstream notls13 {
    server 127.0.0.1:4444;
}

map $remote_addr $upstream {
    4.5.6.7     notls13;
    default     normal;
}

stream {
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
    }
}

http {
    server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        listen 4443 ssl http2;
        include acme;
        location /synchrony {
                allow 127.0.0.0/8;
                allow xxx;
                deny all;
                ...
        }

        location / {
                allow 127.0.0.0/8;
                allow xxx;
                allow xxx;
                deny all;
                ...
        }
        ssl on;
        ...
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers 'xxx'
    }
    # special server for no TLS 1.3
    server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        listen 4444 ssl http2;
        include acme;
        location /synchrony {
                allow 127.0.0.0/8;
                allow xxx;
                deny all;
                ...
        }

        location / {
                allow 127.0.0.0/8;
                allow xxx;
                allow xxx;
                deny all;
                ...
        }
        ssl on;
        ...
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'xxx'
    }
}
```